# Why does turning off my monitors abort hibernation?

Tags: debian, hibernate

I have noticed many times that if I tell my computer to hibernate, then turn off my monitors and KVM (by turning off the power strip they are both attached to) before the hibernation is complete, then it seems to abort hibernation.  This sometimes happens even if I wait until after the screen reverts to just a blinking text-mode cursor.

The result is that the computer never powers off, and when I turn the monitors back on, the screen saver is running (or after a sufficiently long time, the screens have blanked of course, but moving the mouse wakens the screen saver immediately).

Why is this happening? And is there any way I can make it stop doing this? Or am I going to always be stuck waiting for hibernate to complete before I turn off my monitors?

I'm using Debian 6.0.2 (squeeze), with kernel 2.6.32-5-amd64, and two nVidia Quadro FX 570 graphics cards, and three Samsung SyncMaster 245T monitors. Only one of the monitors is going through my IOGGEAR Miniview DVI 4-port KVM, the other two are plugged in directly to the video card ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your KVM.
It's probably sending some signal through the keyboard when it loses power.

Try hibernating without the KVM.

Comment: ha! Good call. I'm a little embarrassed I didn't think of that myself. But sure enough, moving my KVM to a different power switch (that I don't use to shut off my monitors) prevents the aborted hibernation. Thanks.